# Is sem_timedwait defined if the time to wait is 0

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, semaphore

Is `sem_timedwait` defined if the time to wait is 0 or should I call `sem_trywait` in this condition? Documentation is unclear and source code shows only the implementation.

I want to know if Posix standard says something about the case when time has not expired and it is not in the future.

## EDIT

Decided to do not be lazy:

```
        switch(xTicksToWait)
        {
            case SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT:
                result = sem_wait(sem);
                break;
            case SEMAPHORE_NOWAIT:
                result = sem_trywait(sem);
                break;
            default:
                ts.tv_sec += xTicksToWait / 1000;
                ts.tv_nsec += (xTicksToWait % 1000) * 1000000ULL;
                ts.tv_sec += ts.tv_nsec / 1000000000ULL;
                ts.tv_nsec = ts.tv_nsec % 1000000000ULL;
                result = sem_timedwait(sem, &ts);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: The [Open Group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_timedwait.html) page does not say it is the time to wait, but the absolute time: *The timeout shall expire when the absolute time specified by `abstime` passes, as measured by the clock on which timeouts are based (that is, when the value of that clock equals or exceeds abstime), or if the absolute time specified by abstime has already been passed at the time of the call.* Even if a time interval is specified, it doesn't seem unclear.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know the documentation and I know that is absolute time. I think it is quite easy to understand what I mean. The case: not expired and not in the future. Otherwise what is the point of `sem_trywait` (except saving the keyboard?)?

Comment: The time has already expired: the document is very clear: *equals or exceeds*.

Comment: What is the point of `printf()` when we can serve all the same purposes and more with `fprintf()`?  Sometimes APIs are redundant, for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

From [`sem_timedwait(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait):

> `sem_timedwait()` is the same as `sem_wait()`, except that abs_timeout specifies a limit on the amount of time that the call should block if the decrement cannot be immediately performed. The `abs_timeout` argument points to a structure that specifies an **absolute timeout in seconds and nanoseconds since the Epoch**, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

An absolute timeout of zero seconds would be the Epoch.

This will always immediately result in one of:

> If the timeout has already expired by the time of the call, and the semaphore could not be locked immediately, then sem_timedwait() fails with a timeout error (errno set to ETIMEDOUT).

> If the operation can be performed immediately, then sem_timedwait() never fails with a timeout error, regardless of the value of abs_timeout. Furthermore, the validity of abs_timeout is not checked in this case.

The example on the manual page shows creating an absolute timeout from a relative time interval (using [`clock_gettime(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime)). A trimmed down snippet:

```
int s;
struct timespec ts;

/* Calculate relative interval as current time plus
       number of seconds given argv[2] */

if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
    handle_error("clock_gettime");

ts.tv_sec += atoi(argv[2]);

while ((s = sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    continue;       /* Restart if interrupted by handler */

/* Check what happened */

if (s == -1) {
    if (errno == ETIMEDOUT)
        printf("sem_timedwait() timed out\n");
    else
        perror("sem_timedwait");
} else
    printf("sem_timedwait() succeeded\n");
```

---

An invalid argument to be aware of is:

> **EINVAL**
> The value of `abs_timeout.tv_nsecs` is less than 0, or greater than or equal to 1000 million.

Comment: Thank you - but it does not answer my question.I know the documentation, And posting examples from there makes no sense at all. I was hoping to get the answer from someone who **knows** it.

Comment: @0___________ The quoted documentation is very clear about what happens with a time that's in the past. *not expired and not in the future* Can you describe an example of such a time?

Comment: If it was clear I would not ask this question